# Neo4j.rb How to use it with Rails

Tags: cypher, neo4j.rb

I am using neo4j version 3.X, I am using searchkick

**currently using**

```
User.search(params[:term], operator: 'or',
     fields: [:first_name, :last_name],
     misspellings: { below: 5 },
     match: :word_start,
    page: params[:page], per_page: params[:rpp], padding: params[:offset])
```

**instead of**

```
User.where('(sp.first_name + sp.last_name) =~ ?', /.*#{params[:term].sub(/\s/, '')}.*/i)
```

But I have problem where I have to make more cypher queries at the same time with searching How to do that?

For exmaple

```
Neo4j::ActiveBase.new_query.match(n: {User: { uuid: current_user.uuid }}).break
               .match('(n)-[:connected_to {status: 2}]-(sp:User)')
               .return('DISTINCT sp')
```

I want to seach in this query with elasctic search with first name & last name

In my model I have defined `searchkick word_start: [:first_name, :last_name]`

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used `searchkick`, but I would suggest trying to use the `ActiveNode` syntax instead of the `neo4j-core` `Query` syntax so that you can append `.search` on the end:

```
current_user.connected_users.rel_where(status: 2).distinct.search(...)
```

This is assuming that there is a `connected_users` association which uses the `connected_to` relationship type.  You may have another, similar, association in your `User` model but I didn't know what it was.

I'm not 100% sure if the `distinct` will work with the `search` or not, but you could perhaps drop the `.distinct` part and `searchkick` might return you a distinct set anyway.